# How does resetting an index with the modulus operator work?

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing, modulus

I know that modulus returns the remainder of a division, but I don't understand how that works when you need to reset an array index.

Let's say we have this code:

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3]
let index = 0

for 1...6 {
    let item = numbers[index % numbers.count]
    print(item)
    index += 1
}
```

I understand that the operation before index is equal to numbers.count, it will return index. I also understand that when index reaches 3, the number of items in the array, it will return 0 (which will display the first item of the array). However, I don't understand how it continues displaying the array in order after that.

If index is 4, then the operation performed is 4 divided by 3, which returns a remainder of 1. So then, the displayed numbers would be 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, right? I mean, index is never assigned back to 0, so it will just continue to increment.

How does the modulus method of resetting an index work after you have reached the end of the array?

And why is the modulus method better than the below method of resetting an index?

```
if index >= numbers.count {
    index = 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your description is off just a bit. `index` is being iterated starting with 0, not 1 (don't confuse the line `for 1...6` with the values of `index`.

Do the math. You iterate `index` from 0 to 5. `numbers.count` is 3.

For each index, result is `index % numbers.count`.

```
index:   0 1 2 3 4 5
result:  0 1 2 0 1 2
item:    1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Comment: I think I understand now, but why is the modulus method better than using an if statement to assign the index back to 0?

Comment: It depends on how index is being used. In the code in your question, either way works just fine. But there might be a case where you need the index for more than one use.

Comment: So when I don't need index for something else, it's fine to default to the if statement method? The class I'm talking used the if statement method and never covered the modulus method.

Comment: Sure, using the `if` instead of the `%` is fine for the code in your question.